# macOS Keychain Sharing Bypass Password Dialog

Tags: swift, macos, keychain

I'm trying to build an application that uses Keychain Sharing on macOS. But when trying to access the keychain data, it shows the following dialog.

[image: macOS Keychain Dialog]

This creates a very poor user experience where the user is forced to enter their computer password in order to use the application.

I have not experienced this problem on iOS.

How can I bypass this dialog? All of the applications are signed under the same development team, so I don't think it should be an issue.

Comment: @Willeke My keychain password matches my user login password. So that doesn't look like the problem.

Comment: Is the password asked every time or only once for each build?

Answer (score 2):

Apps from the same developer don't automatically share access to keychain items; you have to explicitly set up some sort of sharing policy. How you do that depends on whether the item is being stored in an iCloud keychain or an old-style keychain.

For items in iCloud keychains, you need to define an access group, add your apps to the group, and set the `kSecAttrAccessGroup` attribute for your keychain item(s) to that group. See the Apple dev document ["Sharing Access to Keychain Items Among a Collection of Apps"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps) for details.

For items in non-iCloud (old-style) keychains, you need to define an access control list for each item that lists each app that should be granted access, and what type of access. See the Apple dev document ["Access Contr Lists"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/access_control_lists) for details.

Note: I think the dialog box in the question indicates a non-iCloud keychain item. If you enter the password and click "Always Allow", it will add an access control entry granting that app access to the item. You can view the access control list in the Keychain Access utility.

Comment: So I realized I should be using iCloud keychain but I'm not. According to [this](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift#synchronizing-keychain-items-with-other-devices) `We could not get the Keychain synchronization work on macOS.`. Not sure how that can be fixed. But looks like I'm running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using the new keychain storage format, that also supports synchronization (iCloud Keychain) and is the only storage format available on iOS devices, you can only share keychain items through either keychain access groups or app groups. When an app writes a keychain item and it belongs to such a group, all other apps belonging to the same group can read it without the system prompting the user for access.

Apple has documented everything you need to know in all detail on this page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

See also my following reply about this topic for some more hints:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728698/15809

When using the old keychain storage format, whose items are not synchronizable, access is controlled by a SecAccessRef object which is stored together with every keychain item. See these pages for details (especially the images are pretty helpful):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/access_control_lists

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1393522-secaccesscreate

With the old format you need to explicitly name the apps that are allowed to access the item and you need to specify which operations they are allowed to perform.